# knockout.js with optionsValue and value

Tags: knockout.js

Is there a way to keep the `value` binding to the object, but have the `optionsValue` be a property on the object.  As of now if I specify both, the `optionsValue` property that is selected will populate the `value` binding.  Id like to keep the object intact in the observable, but specify what value to be set in the select list value.  This way a form submit will send the `optionsValue` I chose.

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(q => q.DivisionId, new SelectList(Enumerable.Empty<string>()), new { data_bind="options: divisions, optionsText: 'Name', optionsValue: 'Id', value: division, optionsCaption: ' - '" })

function AddCrossPoolGameDialog() {
    var self = this;

    self.divisions = ko.observableArray([]);
    self.division = ko.observable();

    self.awayDivisionTeams = ko.computed(function () {
        var division = ko.utils.arrayFirst(self.divisions(), function(item) {
            return self.division.Name() == item.Name;
        });

        if (division) {
            return division.DivisionTeamPools;
        }

        return [];
    });
}
```

Comment: It sounds pretty simple to write a binding for this sort of behavior. I don't know of a built in way. Another way is to simply use two different properties for the value and the submit. Another question, if the property isn't really observing changed why is it an observable property?

Comment: Some other dropdowns are dependent on it to show/hide.

Comment: I really can't understand your structure, would you mind creating a very reduced sample of your problem on jsfiddle and posting the code here?

Comment: JsFiddle would not allow the use of Razor syntax, to my knowledge.  Could you not set a @HiddenFor() or @TextBoxFor() equal to DivisonId and set it's value equal to something like selectedDivisionId() with knockout?

Comment: Just copy the HTML/JS/CSS (a _reduced_ example please!) of Razor's _output_ (what your asp.net app is _serving_)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You can't get both the `optionsValue` and `value` bindings to point to different objects, but you can create a simple workaround.

In order to get your form to submit a simple value, use `optionsValue` to point to your bound item's property that you want posted with the form. Then assign the `value` binding to an observable. Last, create a `computed` to automatically find and return the correct object when the selected value changes.

Example bindings:

```
<select data-bind="options: options,
                   optionsText: 'name',
                   optionsValue: 'id',
                   value: selectedOptionId"></select>
<br/>
<br/>
Selection Option Object : <span data-bind="text: selectedOption"></span><br/>
Selection Option name : <span data-bind="text: selectedOption().name"></span><br/>
Selection Option id : <span data-bind="text: selectedOption().id"></span><br/>
```

and view model :

```
var optionModel = function(id,name){
    var self = this;
    self.id = id;
    self.name = name;
}

var viewModel = function(){
    var self = this;
    self.options = [
        new optionModel(1,"First"),
        new optionModel(2,"Second")
    ];
    self.selectedOptionId = ko.observable(self.options[0].id);
    self.selectedOption = ko.computed(function(){
        return ko.utils.arrayFirst(self.options, function(item){
            return item.id === self.selectedOptionId();
        });
    });
}

ko.applyBindings(new viewModel());
```

[I've posted this to a jsFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/rrahlf/xjYcu/).

Hope this helps!

Comment: what a p.i.t.a this is to get it working for global form validation, thanks!

Comment: Maintaining KO code is a nightmare, why did past me didn't use anything else - oh wait, the Po(S)C needed to run in IE8...