# Knockout/Select2: problems getting dropdowns to work correctly for book transfer application

Tags: asp.net-mvc, knockout.js, jquery-select2

So I'm having trouble with my application that I'm trying to complete. It's supposed to send a list of changes I want for possessions of books. Right now I have a couple viewmodels in knockout that contains data that has been passed in through json.

I've been trying to get the dropdowns populated with the correct lists and track the changes that happen, but I'm not having any luck. This is the binding that I've been trying to use to attach the lists to the dropdowns. I am able to populate them but I cannot select anything.

```js
 function BookPossessionTransferVM() {
    var self = this;
    self.AllFromList = ([
      {"IsAdult":false,"Name":"Bob","ID":38438}, 
      {"IsAdult":false,"Name":"Gordon","ID":54686}
    ]);
    self.PossessionChanges  = ko.observableArray([]);
    self.PossessionChanges.push(new PossessionChangeModel());
    self.AvailableFrom = ko.computed(function() {
      var possessionChangesValues = self.PossessionChanges(),
          available = ko.utils.arrayFilter(self.AllFromList, function(selectedPerson) {
            return !ko.utils.arrayFirst(possessionChangesValues , function (possessionChange) {
              if (possessionChange.SelectedFrom() !== undefined) {
                return possessionChange!= self && 
                       possessionChange.SelectedFrom().Name() === selectedPerson.Name;
              } else {
                return false;
              }});
          });
      return available;
    });
    self.AvailableTo = ko.computed(function() {
       var possessionChangesValues = self.PossessionChanges(),
          available = ko.utils.arrayFilter(self.AllToList, function(selectedPerson) {
            return !ko.utils.arrayFirst(possessionChangesValues , function (possessionChange) {
              if (possessionChange.SelectedFrom() !== undefined) {
                return possessionChange!= self && 
                       possessionChange.SelectedFrom().Name() === selectedPerson.Name;
              } else {
                return false;
              }});
          });
      return available;
    });
    self.addPossessionChange = function () {
      self.PossessionChanges.push(new PossessionChangeModel());
    }
    self.removePossessionChangeChange = function(possessionChange) {
      self.PossessionChanges.remove(possessionChange);
    }
}

function PossessionChangeModel() {
    var self = this;
    self.SelectedFrom = ko.observable(new SelectedPerson());
    self.SelectedTo = ko.observable(new SelectedPerson());
    self.ChangeType = ko.pureComputed(function() {
      if (self.SelectedFrom() !== undefined && self.SelectedTo() !== undefined) {
        return 'Update';
      } else if (self.SelectedFrom() === undefined && self.SelectedTo() === undefined) {
          return '';
      } else if (self.SelectedFrom() === undefined) {
        return 'Add';
      } else if (self.SelectedTo() === undefined) {
        return 'Remove';
      } else { return ''; }
    });
}

function SelectedPerson() {
  var self = this;

  self.IsAdult  = ko.observable(false);
  self.Name = ko.observable("None");
  self.ID = ko.observable(0);
}
 
 ko.bindingHandlers.select2 = {
    init: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, bindingContext) {
      ko.utils.domNodeDisposal.addDisposeCallback(element,
        function() {
          $(element).select2('destroy');
        });
      var select2 = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(allBindingsAccessor().options);
      $(element).select2(select2);
    },
    update: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, bindingContext) {
      var allBindings = allBindingsAccessor();
      if ("value" in allBindings) {
        if ((allBindings.select2.multiple || element.multiple) && allBindings.value().constructor != Array) {
          $(element).val(allBindings.value().split(',')).trigger('change');
        } else {
          $(element).on('select2:selecting', function(e) {
              var data = e.params.args.data.id;
              console.log(data);
            });
          $(element).val(allBindings.value()).trigger('change');
        }
      }
      $(element).trigger("change");
    }
};
  
ko.applyBindings(new BookPossessionTransferVM());
```

```css
  #tblPossessionChanges {
    width: 70%;
    height: 100px;
    text-align: center;
    table-layout: fixed;
  }

  #tblReassignChanges td, #tblPossessionChanges th {
    padding: 1rem;
  }

  #tblReassignChanges thead th {
    text-align: center;
  }

  #tblReassignChanges thead th:first-child {
    text-align: left;
    width: 10%;
  }

  #tblReassignChanges tbody td:first-child {
    text-align: left;
    width: 10%;
  }

  #tblReassignChanges > tbody > tr > td.prompt > a{
    font-weight: bold;
  }

  #tblReassignChanges tbody td select{
    width: 75%
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.12/js/select2.full.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.12/css/select2.min.css" />
<div>
  <table id="tblReassignChanges">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th><a href="#" class="buttonSmall" data-bind="click: addPossessionChange">Add</a></th>
        <th>From</th>
        <th>To</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody data-bind="foreach: PossessionChanges">
      <tr>
        <td class="prompt">
          <a href="#" class="buttonSmall" data-bind="click: $root.removePossessionChange">Delete</a>           </td>
        <td>
          <select class="form-control" 
                  data-bind="options: $root.AvailableFrom, 
                             value: SelectedFrom,
                             optionsText: 'Name', 
                             optionsValue: 'ID',
                             select2: { placeholder: 'Please select a Person...', allowClear: true}">             </select>
        </td>
        <td>
          <select class="form-control"
                  data-bind="options: $root.AvailableTo, 
                             value: SelectedTo, 
                             optionsText: 'Name', 
                             optionsValue: 'ID',
                             select2: {placeholder: 'Please select a Person...', allowClear: true}">            </select>
        </td>
        <td>
          <span id="changeTypeSpan" data-bind="text: ChangeType"></span>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

I've also tried changing the optionsValue to use the ID but then that overrides the selectedPerson objects that I have. I am open to all suggestions and help. Thank you!

EDIT: Here is the jsFiddle that replicates my issue and so that it saves space. I hard coded in data as well. https://jsfiddle.net/3upb0mf8/5/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've got multiple problems here:

1. The main issue is that you assume that `possessionChange.SelectedFrom()` contains the entire person object, while actually it only contains its id, because that's what's passed to `optionsValue`. Please [read this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17289106/3002584) to fully understand it. You must retrieve the person by its id.
2. `AvailableTo` refers to `possessionChange.SelectedFrom()` instead of `possessionChange.SelectedTo()`.
3. name conflict: `removePossessionChange` vs `removePossessionChangeChange`.
4. A `PossesionChange` must have an id so it can be deleted.

And few other problems.

I think I fixed most of the problems. Also note I'm using a `PersonVM` instead of plain objects:

```js
function BookPossessionTransferVM() {
  var self = this;
  self.All = [new PersonVM(false,"Bob",38438), new PersonVM(false,"Gordon",54686)];
  self.PossessionChanges  = ko.observableArray([]);
  self.AvailableFrom = ko.computed(function() {
    var available = ko.utils.arrayFilter(self.All, function(item) {
      return !ko.utils.arrayFirst(self.PossessionChanges() , function (possessionChange) {
         var person = self.getPersonById(possessionChange.SelectedFrom());
         if (person) {

          return person.Name() === item.Name();
         } else {
           return false;
         }
      });
    });
    return available;
  });
  self.AvailableTo = ko.computed(function() {
    var available = ko.utils.arrayFilter(self.All, function(item) {
      return !ko.utils.arrayFirst(self.PossessionChanges() , function (possessionChange) {
        var person = self.getPersonById(possessionChange.SelectedTo());
         if (person) {
          return person.Name() === item.Name();
        } else {
          return false;
        }});
    });
    return available;
  });
  self.getPersonById = function (id) {
    return ko.utils.arrayFirst(self.All, function(person){
          return person.ID === id;
      });
  }
  self.addPossessionChange = function () {
    self.PossessionChanges.push(new PossessionChangeVM(self.PossessionChanges.length + 1));
  }
  self.removePossessionChange = function(possesion) {
    self.PossessionChanges.remove(function (item) {
      return possesion.possesionId() == item.possesionId();
    });
  }
}

function PossessionChangeVM(possesionId) {
  var self = this;
  self.possesionId = ko.observable(possesionId);
  self.SelectedFrom = ko.observable();
  self.SelectedTo = ko.observable();
  self.ChangeType = ko.pureComputed(function() {
    if (self.SelectedFrom() !== undefined && self.SelectedTo() !== undefined) {
      return 'Update';
    } else if (self.SelectedFrom() === undefined && self.SelectedTo() === undefined) {
        return '';
    } else if (self.SelectedFrom() === undefined) {
      return 'Add';
    } else if (self.SelectedTo() === undefined) {
      return 'Remove';
    } else { return ''; }
  });
}

function PersonVM(isAdult, name, id) {
  var self = this;

  self.IsAdult  = ko.observable(isAdult);
  self.Name = ko.observable(name);
  self.ID = ko.observable(id);
}
 ko.bindingHandlers.select2 = {
  init: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, bindingContext) {
    ko.utils.domNodeDisposal.addDisposeCallback(element,
      function() {
        $(element).select2('destroy');
      });
    var select2 = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(allBindingsAccessor().options);
    $(element).select2(select2);
  },
  update: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, bindingContext) {
    var allBindings = allBindingsAccessor();
    if ("value" in allBindings) {
      if ((allBindings.select2.multiple || element.multiple) && allBindings.value().constructor != Array) {
        $(element).val(allBindings.value().split(',')).trigger('change');
      } else {
        $(element).on('select2:selecting', function(e) {
            var data = e.params.args.data.id;
          });
        $(element).val(allBindings.value()).trigger('change');
      }
    }
    $(element).trigger("change");
  }
};
ko.applyBindings(new BookPossessionTransferVM());
```

```css
#tblPossessionChanges {
    width: 70%;
    height: 100px;
    text-align: center;
    table-layout: fixed;
  }

  #tblReassignChanges td, #tblPossessionChanges th {
    padding: 1rem;
  }

  #tblReassignChanges thead th {
    text-align: center;
  }

  #tblReassignChanges thead th:first-child {
    text-align: left;
    width: 10%;
  }

  #tblReassignChanges tbody td:first-child {
    text-align: left;
    width: 10%;
  }

  #tblReassignChanges > tbody > tr > td.prompt > a{
    font-weight: bold;
  }

  #tblReassignChanges tbody td select{
    width: 75%
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.12/js/select2.full.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.12/css/select2.min.css" />
<div>
  <table id="tblReassignChanges">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th><a href="#" class="buttonSmall" data-bind="click: addPossessionChange">Add</a></th>
        <th>From</th>
        <th>To</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody data-bind="foreach: PossessionChanges">
      <tr>
        <td class="prompt">
          <a href="#" class="buttonSmall" data-bind="click: $root.removePossessionChange">Delete</a>           </td>
        <td>
          <select class="form-control" 
                  data-bind="options: $root.AvailableFrom, 
                             value: SelectedFrom,
                             optionsText: 'Name', 
                             optionsValue: 'ID',
                             select2: { placeholder: 'Please select a Person...', allowClear: true}">             </select>
        </td>
        <td>
          <select class="form-control"
                  data-bind="options: $root.AvailableTo, 
                             value: SelectedTo, 
                             optionsText: 'Name', 
                             optionsValue: 'ID',
                             select2: {placeholder: 'Please select a Person...', allowClear: true}">            </select>
        </td>
        <td>
          <span id="changeTypeSpan" data-bind="text: ChangeType"></span>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: thank you so much for your help! I just had a question about a couple of the changes you made. What's the biggest difference between your PersonVM and my SelectedPerson? I thought that mine was a vm as well instead of just a plain object. 
also what's the difference between `self.PossessionChanges.push(new PossessionChangeVM(self.PossessionChanges.length + 1));
  }` vs what I had?

Comment: @M.Bi, I renamed it to `PersonVM` for semantic reasons: plainly, it's a person; it's not necessarily a *selected* person. also, it's a good practice to give it the `VM` suffix to identify it explicitly as a view model. Also, note that I'm passing it arguments for its observables. Now, what I did with `PossessionChangeVM` is pass it an id (which simply represents the row number, nothing particulary clever here), which is necessary for the removal functionality.

Comment: ah that makes sense.  For the PossessionChangeVM.SelectedFrom, why did you change it from a new PersonVM() to just a plain ko.oberservable? If I still wanted to track the selection of it, wouldn't I want it to track the PersonVM?

Comment: Your'e asking about the exact thing I stressed in my first point in my answer, so I suggest you reread it. but again: `SelectedFrom` doesn't hold a `personVM` object; it just *can't*, that's how `options` binding works. what it holds is a simple number (the person id), that's passed to `optionsValue`. There's no way around it.

Comment: I'm dumb.. you're right. It's exactly the first point you were making. Would I be able to have the inital value of the dropdowns be empty erm 0 so that it has no initial selection? My end goal is to be able to send a list of the "changes" via json when I submit this form

Comment: They currently don't have an initial selection (that is, a selected *value*), the user should make a selection. maybe you mean no initial *options*? so just initialize `AvailableFrom` and `AvailableTo` later. In any case, I think it would be fair to say that your question is now answered. If other things comes up, you are of course invited to ask another question after doing your research.

Comment: If they had no initial options, wouldn't that mean the dropdownlist would be blank? Also if I am not able to track the ids, is it still possible for me to use AvailableFrom to reduce the list if there is a selection?

Comment: (1) Yap, the dropdowns would be empty. If you need something else, take a good thought, do some research, and I'm sure you'll find a solution (and if not, ask another question). But this is outside the *current* question boundaries, which need to be respected here in StackOverflow (2) You must have a unique key to identify a person, be it an id or something else.

Comment: @M.Bi, if you consider my answer as resolving your question, please mark it as accepted (tick the V icon to the upper-left of the answer).