# how to bind data in the dropdownlist using knockout

Tags: data-binding, knockout.js

i have this dropdownlist list but it won't bind on the specific record that i needed. e.g If i create a record and then select from the dropdownlist "workflow name 1" for the workflow field and then i save the changes. i will go back to the list and then i will open the record that i created but when the details loaded the dropdownlist does not select the "workflow name 1" but it only selects the "Select a workflow" instead of the "workflow name 1"

```
        <select id="workflow-name" style="width:600px" class="form-control errorInput" data-tooltip="tooltip" data-orientation="right" data-tab="2" data-bind="options: $root.WorkFlowsNameList,optionsCaption:'Select a Workflow',  optionsText: 'ShortDescription', optionsValue: 'ID', value: WorkFlow_ID, attr: {'data-title': window.LabelVM.trigger_details_workflowname, 'data-con': window.LabelVM.trigger_workflowname_popover, 'data-popover': 'popover' }"></select>
```

This is the ko code that renders the data

```
function editData(data, e) {
    localStorage.processId = "";
    router.navigate('#/trigger/' + data.ID() + "/" + data.WorkFlow_ID());
}
```

i'm using the WorkFlow_ID as the parameter to pre select the options value to be displayed but it's doesn't bind at all.

Comment: Did my answer help you resolve your problem? if so, please mark it as accepted. If not, let me know and I'll try to further help you with it.

Comment: @HeyJude thank you for your reply. i tried to use the code you given but still unable to make it work

Comment: Can you add your code you tried to your question?

Comment: @HeyJude i have updated the code which KO uses when displaying the specific data

Comment: I mean add the code you said you tried to use taken from the link in my answer.

Comment: function editData(data, e) {
        localStorage.processId = "";

        wfid = ko.observable(data.WorkFlow_ID());

        this = ko.computed(function () {
            return ko.utils.arrayFirst(data.WorkFlow_ID(), function (item) {
                return item.WorkFlow_ID = wfid;
            });
        });
        router.navigate('#/trigger/' + data.ID() + "/" + data.WorkFlow_ID());
    }

Comment: I can see several things you need to fix, but please add this code it into your question. It will be easier for both of us to understand each other when we see the code formatted nicely.

Comment: done adding it.. im not really knowledgeable with ko. i have updated the post

Comment: I editted my answer

Answer (score 0):

You're experiencing a common error when using `optionsValue` together with `value`.

When you specify both, the value of the property bounded to `optionsValue` will populate the object bounded to `value`.
The problem is that Knockout can't know how to use that value to get an object from the bounded `options`.

So, if you use both, you should bound a computed observable (or a simple function) to `value`, whose job is to retrieve (from wherever it should) the correct object.

[See here an example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17289106/3002584).

EDIT:
Please read [`options` documentation](https://knockoutjs.com/documentation/options-binding.html) before going forward,  otherwise the following won't help you.

The code you added has several issues. The main problem is that this is not the code that defines your view model, as I don't see `WorkFlowsNameList` in it.

So I'll assume you somewhere have that code, and I'll call it `viewModel` for that matter. It is there you should add the new code:

```
function viewModel(items) {
    var self = this;
    self.WorkFlowsNameList = ko.observableArray(items);  
    self.WorkFlow_ID = ko.observable();
    self.selectedOption = ko.computed(function(){
        return ko.utils.arrayFirst(self.WorkFlowsNameList, function(item){
            return item.ID === self.WorkFlow_ID();
        });
    });
}
```